# New cipher problem, how to decode given enciphered code?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, decode, caesar-cipher

While I am trying to solve Caesar cipher, I faced few problems.

```
#enciphered message = 'I wtvp olel decfnefcpd lyo lwrzctesxd'

plain = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

cipher = 'lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk'
cipher_text = input('Enter enciphered message: ')
clean_text = ' '

for i in cipher_text:

    if i != " ":
        clean_text = clean_text + plain[plain.index(cipher[(ord(i)-ord('a'))])]
    else:
        clean_text = clean_text + " "

print(clean_text)
```

Above is the code, that I created and this is what I got as a result:

```
Enter enciphered message: I wtvp olel decfnefcpd lyo lwrzctesxd

 n hega zwpw opnqypqnao wjz whcknepdio
```

Here are my related questions:

1. Why wasn't it decoded properly? Like, It should be 'I like data structures and algorithms'
2. I'm also confused about the capital "I" at the beginning of the enciphered message. Do you have any insight on that?
3. Finally I have no idea how to decode uppercase and lowercase at the same time; how should I do that?

Comment: A small point.  What you call "clean text" is normally called "plaintext".

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Why wasn't it decoded properly? Like, It should be 'I like data structures and algorithms'

First of all, the alphabet is already present in ASCII. So there is no need to redefine the alphabet in `plain` or `cipher`. The key is the offset from the plaintext character to the ciphertext character, wrapping around directly after the `z`.

So you generally convert from a character to an index in the alphabet from 0..25, then you add (for encryption) or subtract (for decryption) the key, modulo 26 - the size of the alphabet. Then, to get the result, you convert back into a character. You're already doing the conversion to index using `ord(character) - ord(a)`. The opposite can be done using `chr`.

> (2) I'm also confused about the capital "I" at the beginning of the enciphered message. Do you have any insight on that?

Well, there are more possibilities for single character words. The word `A` would be a prime suspect.

> (3) Finally I have no idea how to decode uppercase and lowercase at the same time; how should I do that?

The best way is to create a variable that indicates that something is uppercase or not; `is_uppercase` would be a good name. Then convert the character to lowercase. Perform the encryption / decryption operation and then convert the resulting character back into uppercase, if required. That way your encryption / decryption operation is not affected at all and kept relatively simple.